# undefined index php $_POST dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, post

i'm trying to learn some basic php, i've some difficult to get post value from a dropdown menu.
I've that error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: mese in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ethermine/class.php on line 3
```

i don't know why, the index `mese` exist on my dropdown menu, it's name attribute of select tag like you can see on my code.
So why i've that error?
I see many many error on stackoverflow but it seems that the code is ok but of course i'm wrong.

**test.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="class.php" method="POST">
    <select name="mese">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="01">Gennaio</option>
        <option value="02">Febbraio</option>
        <option value="03">Marzo</option>
        <option value="04">Aprile</option>
        <option value="05">Maggio</option>
        <option value="06">Giugno</option>
        <option value="07">Luglio</option>
        <option value="08">Agosto</option>
        <option value="09">Settembre</option>
        <option value="10">Ottobre</option>
        <option value="11">Novembre</option>
        <option value="12">Dicembre</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="scelta" value="Scegli il mese" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**class.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["mese"])){
    $sceltaMese = $_POST["mese"];
    echo $sceltaMese;
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: $sceltaMese = @$_POST["mese"];

Comment: `if (!isset($_POST["mese"]))` is a typo. Remove the negation. That's why you're getting that error.

Comment: @DhiarjSharma why would you want them to suppress?

Comment: Are you submitting the form without selecting an option? If that's allowable, you'll need to test existing before trying to access. You could also set a default option.

Comment: To:  `if (isset($_POST["mese"])){` - remove the `!`

Comment: Oh sorry you're right!
Thanks for your big help

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner There you go, you can TYPO it now

Comment: @RiggsFolly done ;-) thank buddy.

Comment: FYI: Typos usually end up getting deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class.php

insert this:

```
if (isset($_POST["mese"])){
   $sceltaMese = $_POST["mese"];
   echo $sceltaMese;
 } else {
  //do something for error
 }
```

you made a mistake by using `!`. so if the post was not set it would do that. Now without `!` if the post is set it will run those lines.

Comment: I was just about to vote this one out as a typo, but someone else duped it before I could. IMHO, it was a typo which is the reason I did not post an answer for.

Comment: @tafazzi87 could you mark the answer as correct for other users :)

Comment: @JamesBond can you give the guy time for it? you have 8 mins. left to go.